# include A python file that exisist in the project

Tags: python

Im totaly new to python so i am in the absolute beginner stage.
I know alot PHP so my mind think in the PHP way when i am trying stuff with Python.

I have a python project that contains a:

**test.py


Includes(folder)


 - math.py**

The test.py contains the code:

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1",
                 user="root", 
                  passwd="", 
                  db="python")


from Tkinter import *




root = Tk()
root.title("test")
root.geometry("500x500")
window = Frame(root)
window.grid()
label = Label(text="")
label.grid()
def click():
cur = db.cursor() 
query = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM names")
result = cur.fetchall()
label["text"] = result[0]

b1 = Button(window, text = "Click me!",command=click)
b1.grid()   
root.mainloop()
```

How do i include the math.py file so i can use the class inside. I know in PHP it's:

```
include("indcludes/math.py");
```

But how do you make the same thing in Python, if its posible at all ;)

Ty for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an empty file called __init__.py in your `includes` folder.

```
$ touch includes/__init__.py
```

In your client code `test.py`, import the math.py class through

```
from includes import math
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding this

```
from includes import math
```

For above line to work you need to create an empty file in the `includes` folder with name `__init__.py`. This will make the folder a package ([ref](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages))

Comment: The empty file shall have the name `__init__.py` or init.py ?

Ty for your quick replys guys.

Comment: file name should be `__init.__py`. Refer to http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages for documentation